# Not able to partition the hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have an already created table with 3 partitions. I want to add a new column as a partition in the table.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about creating a new partition column in an already partitioned hive table. I would say no,you can't do so. e.g Suppose you created a table office like this

hive> describe office;

empid  int
empname string
address                 string
year                    string
month                   string
day                     string

Partition Information
col_name                data_type

year                    string
month                   string
day                     string
as much i know you can't add another column say 'hour'. so if you want to add a new partition column one method is by creating a new table with new partition scheme and moving old data to new table.

But if you're asking about adding another partition for year,month,day column you can surely do that. Let me add a picture to show how to do that.
[image]